# Why does the bounced part with the mirror modifier go through the mesh

Tags: modeling, modifiers

At first, I added a circle with 10 vertices, then I extruded it, removed two vertices and turned on the mirror modifier, and that's how I got this error.[image]

I would like to know what I have to do to make the reflected part of the modifier not go through the mesh and to be like this;

[image]

Comment: Enable the Clipping option of the Mirror modifier and see if it fixes your problem?

Comment: I've just tried but it's still the same

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=g2L59lL4" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/g2L59lL4/) here you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display the local orientation of your object, as you can see it is not aligned with the global orientation, so it probably deceives you. Switch back to *Object* mode and apply the rotation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>).

[image]

Comment: Okay, Now I'm gonna try

Comment: Oooh, thank a lot, bro